$f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x$, yet $g(x)$ is not the inverse of $f(x)$

$f(g(x)) = x\;\,$ for all $x\;,$
yet $\,g(x)\,$ is not the inverse of $\,f(x)\,.$

I tried to find the inverse function of $\;2\sin(3x - 4)\;$ in range $\left[\frac{4}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6},\frac{4}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6}\right]$ in the following manner:
\begin{align*}
y &= 2 \sin(3x - 4) \\
\frac{y}{2} &= \sin(3x - 4) \\
\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) &= 3x - 4 \\
3x &= \arcsin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) + 4 \\
x &= \frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) + 4}{3}.
\end{align*}
If we try to substitute again $\;2\sin(3x - 4)\;$ for $\,y\,,\,$ we indeed get $\,x\,.\,$ Yet if one were to trace both graphs, we would get two curves that aren't mirror images of one another.
How can that be?
Thank you for your comments and responses.

Adding/subtracting multiples of $\pi$ would work

$a = \sin b$ does not imply $\arcsin a = b$. The latter imply the former.

@ТymaGaidash, the range $\left[\frac{4}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6},\frac{4}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6}\right]$ is not correct, please correct it.

@Angelo You meant to ping the OP

@Angelo, why is it not correct? If we solve the inequality $ \frac{\pi}{2} \leq 3x - 4 \leq \frac{3\pi}{2} $ We get this range.

Tymoteusz, look at the range you wrote your post, it is not what you get in your comment.

There are left inverses and right inverses.
If $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in D_g$ then $g$ is a right inverse for $f$.
If $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in D_f$ then $g$ is a left inverse for $f$.
If $g$ is both a left and right inverse for $f$ then $g$ is the inverse of $f$.
If $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$ then $g$ is only a right inverse of $f$.

As you know:
$f(x) = 2 \sin(3x-4)$ is not an injective function on $\mathbb{R}$: different $x$ can give the same value. Therefore it doesn't have an inverse on $\mathbb{R}$, because you could take some $y$ for which both $y=f(x_1)$ and $y=f(x_2)$, but $f^{-1}(y)$ could not be both $x_1$ and $x_2$.
You can restrict the domain of $f$ such that it is injective: for example, if you let $-4/3 \leq x \leq (\pi+4)/3$, then $f$ will have an inverse.

An inverse isn't necessarily given by $x = (1/3)(4+ \sin^{-1}(y/2))$, because the value of $\sin^{-1}$ is always between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. Since $\sin$ is not injective on $\mathbb{R}$, we have to pick a range of values for our 'inverse'. If I ask you "If $\sin(x) = 1$, what is $x$?" you can't give a definite answer; it could be $\pi/2 + 2n\pi$ for any integer $n$. You need to pick a value.
If you restrict your domain to the values of $x$ such that $-\pi/2 \leq 3x-4 \leq \pi/2$, you should find that your inverse works.
